# How can I use the website open library to store information into a database

Tags: html, sql, database, rest

I am trying to make a web page that gets information about books using HTML and to place the information about books into a database to use it. Any idea of how to take the information from the website open library and store it into a database?
here is the link to the API if needed:
https://openlibrary.org/developers/api
thanks in advance.

Comment: They have database dumps that you should use instead of the API. https://openlibrary.org/developers/dumps

Comment: Thank you for your hasty reply, I downloaded the "authors dump (~ 0.3G)"  but I am still unsure how to add it to a database.Thanks.

Comment: We don't even know what kind of database you're using or what kind of server stack your web page will use. Surely you know we can't help without knowing more about what you've already got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If postgreSQL and python is a viable option, LibrariesHacked has a ready-made solution on GitHub for importing and searching Open Library data.

[GitHub: LibrariesHacked / openlibrary-search](https://github.com/LibrariesHacked/openlibrary-search)

> Using a postgreSQL database it should be possible to import the data directly into tables and then do complex searches with SQL.

> Unfortunately the downloads provided are a bit messy. The open library file always errors as the number of columns provided seem to vary. Cleaning it up is difficult as just the text file for editions is 25GB.

> That means another python script to clean up the data. The file openlibrary-data-process.py simply reads in the CSV (python is a little more forgiving about dodgy data) and writes it out again, but only if there are 5 columns.